# How to test apt-listchanges is working when there is no packages to update?

Tags: apt

If I run apt-listchanges on Debian buster it says that db does not exist:

```
apt-listchanges --debug --profile=apt --dump-seen
apt-listchanges: Database /var/lib/apt/listchanges.db failed to load: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I guess that is because of there is no packages to be upgraded. Is there a way to test that the following configuration is working?

```
[apt]
frontend=pager
which=news
email_address=someone                      
email_format=text                                      
confirm=false                                          
headers=false
reverse=false
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
```